# Хотелось бы по кнопке останавливать код другой кнопки, где задержка

Tags: java, android, android-studio

у меня код у кнопки, где задержка на закрытие активити, как я бы мог по нажатию другой кнопки останавливать его?

```
package com.talk.talktools;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ImageView imageView2 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
       ImageView imageView3 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

       imageView3.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
               Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Ты нашел пасхалку! Теперь закрытие приложения! :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "У тебя десять секунд!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               Handler handler = new Handler();
               handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       getActivity().finish();
                   }
               }, 10000); //specify the number of milliseconds
               return false;
           }
       });

       View.OnClickListener ocltg = new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               String url = "SECRET";
               Intent h = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               h.setData(Uri.parse(url));
               startActivity(h);
           }
       }; imageView3.setOnClickListener(ocltg);

       View.OnClickListener ocltgchat = new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               String url = "SECRET";
               Intent g = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               g.setData(Uri.parse(url));
               startActivity(g);
           }
       }; imageView.setOnClickListener(ocltgchat);

       View.OnClickListener oclf0x1d = new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
         String url = "SECRET";
               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
               startActivity(i);
           }
       }; imageView2.setOnClickListener(oclf0x1d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Введите `boolean` переменную, добавьте её проверку в `run()` и если проверка проходит, то выполняйте `getActivity().finish();`, а во второй кнопке меняйте значение этой переменной, чтобы условие в `run()` не выполнилось.

Comment: извините, а можно код для boolean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать переменную как параметр класса

```
boolean b = true;
```

При нажатии на кнопку отмены закрытия пиложения

```
b = false;
```

Код закрытия приложения

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (b)
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }, 10000); //specify the number of milliseconds
    return false;
```

Не забыть где-то снова менять значение переменной b, чтобы можно было всё таки закрыть приложение через 10 секунд

Помимо этого можно попробовать следующее

1.Измените

```
handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)
```

на

```
handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, Object token, long delayMillis)
```

2.Если кнопка Отмены была нажата то

```
removeCallbacks(Runnable r, Object token)
```

3.При этом необходимо создать Runnable не внутри, а внешним, так же, как и Handler handler.
Ссылка для доп информации
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler

Comment: сделал всё так, как описано, но приложение всё равно закрывается, даже если нажать кнопку отмены

Comment: Посмотрите через логи какое значение у переменной в начале, меняется ли оно и какое оно в момент закрытия приложения

Comment: Добавил ещё один вариант

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.talk.talktools;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class fragment1 extends Fragment {

    boolean breakRun;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ImageView imageView2 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
       ImageView imageView3 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

       imageView3.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
               Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Ты нашел пасхалку! Теперь закрытие приложения! :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "У тебя десять секунд!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               Handler handler = new Handler();
               handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                        if(!breakRun){
                            getActivity().finish();
                        }
                   }
               }, 10000); //specify the number of milliseconds
               return false;
           }
       });

       View.OnClickListener ocltg = new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                breakRun = true;
                String url = "SECRET";
                Intent h = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                h.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(h);
           }
       }; imageView3.setOnClickListener(ocltg);

       View.OnClickListener ocltgchat = new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               breakRun = true;
               String url = "SECRET";
               Intent g = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               g.setData(Uri.parse(url));
               startActivity(g);
           }
       }; imageView.setOnClickListener(ocltgchat);

       View.OnClickListener oclf0x1d = new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               breakRun = true;
               String url = "SECRET";
               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
               startActivity(i);
           }
       }; imageView2.setOnClickListener(oclf0x1d);
    }
}
```